# How to make div scale to 100% of browser width?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div id="sidebar">sidebar</div>
<div id="content">content</div>
```

The sidebar is a fixed width of 100px. How do I make the width of content to 100% of the browser width?

http://jsfiddle.net/chickendance/qQQTU/1/

Comment: You can use the [`calc()` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc-notation), e.g. `width: calc(100% - 200px)` since the widths of the first two elements are fixed. http://jsfiddle.net/qQQTU/3/ .. though its [not supported](http://caniuse.com/calc) in IE 8 and below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this with simple CSS:

```
#sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}

#content {
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

***Updated with `wrapper` div:***

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <p>wrapper</p>
    <div id="sidebar">sidebar</div>
    <div id="content">content</div>
    <p>wrapper</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    /* reset */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
    /* for demo purposes only */
    height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
    /* for demo purposes only */
    background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.6);
    height: 100%;
}
#sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;

    /* for demo purposes only */
    background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.6);
    height: 50%;
}
#content {
    margin-left: 100px;

    /* for demo purposes only */
    background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.9);
    height: 50%;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/FK2tL/

Comment: Damn, you beat me by seconds!

Comment: @watson :) I win one every once in awhile.

Comment: That works, thanks. But #sidebar and #content both exist inside #wrapper. For some reason, the width of #content is extending past #wrapper by about 200px, causing horizontal scroll bars to appear.

Comment: @SteveDolan Can you post the relevant HTML & CSS?

Comment: Why is the float: left; needed?

Comment: The `float: left;` removes the sidebar from the flow of the page, allowing the content `div` to be placed at at the same offset as the sidebar. Adding the `margin-left: 100px;` prevents the content from overlapping the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

You have to play with the width % just like the rest of us:

```
 #content {
        background: green;
        float: left;
        width: 75%;
    }
```

I'd also consider adding a parent div of width: 100% as per the box model.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your #content properties to this:

```
#content {
            background: green;
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
            margin-right: -200px;
        }
```

So we are setting 100% width as you require, but offsetting the width of the other two DIVs.  I learned this trick from [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/).